# C# Destructors in RSA Crypto

Tags: c#, design, cryptography

I'm just reviewing some of my code and thought I'd throw this out there for comment.

I have a factory class that builds and returns a class for `RSA` Crypto tasks. It implements `IDisposable`. All the uses of the created `RSA` instances are created with `RSA.Create()` and are wrapped in `using()` statements.

One of the constructors allows an `RSA` instance to be passed into the class. At the moment this instance is also used in the same manner inside the same `using()` statements as `RSA` instance created by this class.

The basic shape of the class is (lots ommitted for brevity):

```
internal sealed class RsaCrypto : IRsaCrypto
{
    ~RsaCrypto()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public RsaCrypto(RSA rsa)
    {
        _rsa = rsa;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                PublicKey = null;
                PrivateKey = null;
            }

            _rsa?.Clear();
            _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

I have two questions really.

A) Is a finalizer here really needed? Can an `RSA` instance be regarded as `unmanaged`? Since it does depend on the OS as to what actually gets created in `RSA.Create()` particularly on non windows boxes. (this is in a .NET Standard 2.0 library).

B) I'm thinking that since the `RSA` instance passed in isn't really "owned" by this class it shouldn't dispose of it in a `using()` statement.

Part of the intention of this class is to help promote best practice I'm just a little unsure of this current design.

Comment: As a library writer, don't write for the user who will do the right thing. Write for the user that makes a mistake, is a complete novice, or is wilfully trying to break your code (particularly when writing a security orientated component). Keep the finaliser.

Comment: Yeah, this was exactly what I was thinking too, and why I designed it this way. Not much of a helper if it allows you to cock it all up! To be honest, a large portion of me thinks I should actually ditch this ctor altogether.

Comment: I mean, in a lot of cases it's actually going to make people write `new RSACryptoServiceProvider()` in their code, exactly what they shouldn't do.

Comment: I would throw an exception out of the finalizer (if C# allows that), to inform the programmer that they forgot to `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

> A) Is a finalizer here really needed?

RSA is a managed abstract class, so it should have its own finalizer if it owns any unmanaged resources.

> B) I'm thinking that since the RSA instance passed in isn't really "owned" by this class it shouldn't dispose of it in a using() statement.

It is a somewhat common pattern to dispose the provided object, but provide a way out if this is not wanted, usually with a `leaveOpen` parameter that defaults to false. See [StreamWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) for a similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the finalizer is there only as a safety measure, for the case the user of your class does not call dispose on an instance. Do **not** call the finalizer destructor, the destructor is only accessible by the CLR, that is the essence of managed code.

If you inject the RSA object as an argument to the constructor you should not mess with it because you do not own it. You own it if you created it and then you should dispose it (if it is disposable). Any other approach blurs responsibilities. I am aware that the .NET framework does not always adhere to this principle, I consider this very unfortunate.